# How to make a <div> adjust horizontally by the user

Tags: javascript

I have a vertical side navigation bar and i would like its width to be horizontally adjustable. May someone please direct me to a tutorial or plugin that would help achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you are going to want to use jQuery with its UI plugin.
It can be as simple as:

```
$("#resizable").resizable();
```

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Resizable